# iOS: xcode instance of a subview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uiview

I have a view with a button and 8 labels, i want to repeat this view with input from the user to customize these labels, so there will be this base view displayed multiple times on the screen and i don't want them to cover up each other, the button and placement of the labels are the same of each view.

How would i programmatically make a new view appear after user input of the instance view and make sure it doesn't cover up any other view, i hope this isn't to broad, i just want to have one set view with a button and 8 labels, copy it multiple times and display the user input, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you are looking for, you want the display to scroll up showing all the different views that have been created by the user, one after the other.

To accomplish this, you can use a [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) and programmatically add the views to the scroll view as needed.  Make sure to increase the contentSize of the scroll view to account for the added views.

Here is some code:

```
UIScrollView *scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

//create and add as many of yourView as necessary for your project - y would be the the offset so it gets displayed under the other views

YourCustomView *yourCustomView = [[YourCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y,self.view.frame.size.width, self .view.frame.size.height)]; 

//populate yourCustomView with the appropriate information...

[scrollview addSubview:yourCustomView];

//when you are done adding your views - w and h are whatever your content dictates they are
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(w, h);   
[self.view addSubview:scrollview];
```

Alternatively, depending on your setup and design, you could use a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell that displays the pertinent info.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I understand that, how do i copy a view, and input it multiple times in the scroll view, how do i add the views programmatically to the scroll view is what I'm asking.

Comment: I still have to do much more, but nice job, you did understand